# Can anybody help me to simplify a regex?

Tags: regex, grep

I want to grep a HTTP access log, but I'm not able to write an efficient regular expression.  Here is what I use now:

```
grep \/console access.log | grep -v .gif | grep -v .js |grep -v .css
```

How can I shorten it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep does not support lookahead, so you'll still have to have two instances:

```
grep /console access.log | grep -v '\.\(gif|js|css\)'
```

With negative lookahead, a smaller, although not necessarily more readable regexp would be

```
^(?!.*?\.(gif|js|css)).*/console.*$
```

Comment: The negative look ahead regex will retain entries in which .gif, .js or .css appear after console.

Comment: You need `grep -E -v '\.(...)' ` or backslashes before *all* the "extended" constructs.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not feel simpler.

```
sed -r -n -e '/\.(js|css|gif)/d' -e '\%/console%p' access.log
```